# Sorting by a nested struct that is preloaded

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is it possible to sort by a column from a nested collection that I fetch using preload in Ecto?

```
users = MyApp.User.find_by_id(1) |> Repo.preload(locations: [:address])
```

I want to order by the Location struct field:  **Location.sort_order**

Answer (score 2):

Preloading accepts a query, as shown in the docs [preload/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries).

```
comments_query = from c in Comment, order_by: c.published_at
Repo.all from p in Post, preload: [comments: ^comments_query]
```

You can also use `join/5` with a subquery for instance, or a fragment.

```
locations = from(l in Locations, order_by: [asc: l.sort_order], select: [l.address])

MyApp.User.find_by_id(1)
|> join(:left, [u], l in subquery(locations), on: l.user_id == u.id)
|> select([u, l], %User{u | locations: l})
|> Repo.one
```

(not sure if ecto 2 supports it but probably does, 3 for sure does)

Comment: So does the ```select: [l.address])``` part of your locations query perform a preload? I need to do this  ```Repo.all from p in Post, preload: [comments: ^comments_query]```  and also get the address in the preload.

Comment: So `address` is another association? I usually don't use preload except for the basic 1to1 assocs. If it is another association then I'm not sure how to order that with preload, I would probably write another join?